# can anyone explain why this list pairing code is not working

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, for-loop

i want to get know how many pair of numbers are present in the list

```
ar=[10 ,20 ,20 ,10 ,10 ,30 ,50 ,10 ,20]
```

this is the list

and i want to get the output 3. because there are 2 pair of 10 and one pair of 20

and this is my code

```
for i in ar:
    print(i)
    if ar.count(i)%2:
        ar.remove(i)
        print('removing ..' ,i)
print('numbers of pairs is : ',len(ar)//2)
print('after removing the odds ',ar)
```

**output**

```
10
20
removing .. 20
10
10
30
removing .. 30
10
20
numbers of pairs is :  3
after removing the odds  [10, 20, 10, 10, 50, 10, 20]
```

why this code is not removing the 50 from the list ?

i'm using jupyter notebook and i run this code onces again and the output is:

```
10
20
10
10
50
removing .. 50
20
numbers of pairs is :  3
after removing the odds  [10, 20, 10, 10, 10, 20]
```

the for loop is not reading the 50 from the array at the first run. that's why this code is not working,  and my question is , why ,for loop is not reading this number ?

Comment: Do not remove from list while iterating on it, never

Comment: The first line may be written `for i in reversed(ar):` and the code will delete starting at the right moving towards the left.

Comment: Use a copy of the `ar` list to manipulate, and only use the `ar` list to iterator:

```ar = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20]
ar2 = ar.copy()

for i in ar:
    print(i)
    if ar2.count(i) % 2:
        ar2.remove(i)
        print('removing ..', i)
        
print('numbers of pairs is:', len(ar2) // 2)
print('after removing the odds', ar2)```

Output:

```10
20
removing .. 20
20
10
10
30
removing .. 30
50
removing .. 50
10
20
numbers of pairs is: 3
after removing the odds [10, 20, 10, 10, 10, 20]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Never** remove from list while iteraring on it, in any language I'd say.

An easy solution is to use a list comprehension and keep the one that matters

```
ar = [elt for elt in ar if not ar.count(elt) % 2]
```

---

Imagine with `[1,2,4,5]` you want to remove even numbers, you'll easy see that you'll miss element that are just after a one that you remove

```
forloop: cursor starts at 0    
cursor on box 0 -> value 1 -> condition NOK

forloop: cursor moves to 1
cursor on box 1 -> value 2 -> condition OK -> remove value 2

forloop: cursor moves to 2
cursor on box 2 -> value 5 -> condition NOK
```

Comment: Spot on.  Nice.  But the `list.count` is quite expensive, -The time complexity of the count(value) method is O(n) for a list with n elements.  So the suggestion works well for a small list, if the list is huge, maybe consider - `collections.Counter` the filter out?